# How to capture item model.index of the dom-repeat template (or iron-list) on Dart side?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

In the following example:

captureIndex.html

```
<template id="lista_produtos" is="dom-repeat" items="{{produtos}}" as="item">
   ...
   <paper-input label="Custo" value="{{item.aquisicao_custo}}"type="number" on-change="calcularPrecoSugeridoEvento"><div prefix>R$</div></paper-input>
   ...
</template>
```

captureIndex.dart

```
@property
List produtos = [
  {
    "produto": "Prego",
    "unidade": "Unitário",
    "margem_contribuicao": 10.0,
    "preco_sugerido": 5.0,
  },
  {
    "produto": "Madeira",
    "unidade": "Unitário",
    "margem_contribuicao": 10.0,
    "preco_sugerido": 5.0,
  }
];

@reflectable
void calcularPrecoSugeridoEvento(Event e, d) {
  DomRepeatModel model = new DomRepeatModel.fromEvent(e);

  // IT´S WORKS. DATA ARE SHOWN!!!!
  Map m = model.item; 
  window.alert(m.toString());

  // IT IS NOT WORKS. INDEX IS NOT SHOWN!!!!
  int i = model.index;
  window.alert(i.toString());
}
```

I would like to capture *model.index*. But it is *null*.

I would not like to use html tag with event, with normally it´s suggested:

```
...
<template id="lista_produtos" is="dom-repeat" items="{{produtos}}" as="item">
   <paper-input id={{index}} on-change="eventX></paper-input>
</template>
...

...
void event (e, d) {
   window.alert((e).attributes['id']));
}
...
```

Is there some form to capture the index through model?

Comment: Your HTML uses `is=dom-if` but otherwise `dom-repeat` in the title of your question. What is it you actually want to know?

Comment: I edited. It is without is=dom-if.

Comment: But also without `is="dom-repeat"`?

Comment: Not! Edited again! Thanks!

Comment: Ok, now I think I got it. My answer shows a few ways to do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`id={{index}}` is a bad idea.

1. You shouldn't bind to the `id` attribute.
2. The `id` attribute must not start with a number. `id="123"` is invalid `id="a123"` or `id="_123"` would work but you still should not bind to the `id` attribute.

If you don't want to use an HTML attribute you can use

```
@reflectable
  calcularPrecoSugeridoEvento(dom.Event event, [_]) {
  ($['lista_produtos'] as DomRepeat)
      .modelForElement(event.target).jsElement['index'];
}
```

If you do want to use an HTML attribute you need to add '$' to the attribute name to actually bind to the attribute (reflected in the DOM) and not to a property (JS only):

```
<paper-input data-index={{index}} on-change="calcularPrecoSugeridoEvento></paper-input>
```

then you can access the `index` using

```
new PolymerEvent(event).localTarget.dataset['index']
// or
new PolymerEvent(event).localTarget.attributes['data-index']
```

For `<template id="lista_produtos" is="dom-repeat" ...>` I successfully used these two variants to get the `DomRepeatModel`

```
  @reflectable
  event([dom.Event event, _]) {
    DomRepeatModel model = ($['lista_produtos'] as DomRepeat)
        .modelForElement(event.target);
    // or
    model = 
        new DomRepeatModel.fromEvent(convertToJs(event));    
    var index = model.index;
  }
```

Comment: Günter, the data I got `model.item`! But I would like the index. In model, we have `model.index` attribute, but it return _null_

Comment: Your last example I wanted! But, for me,  `var index = model.jsElement['index']`  return null. I am using Polymer 1.0 RC2 and SDK 1.12.1.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas. I tried it again and it works for me. You can try to checkout my example https://github.com/bwu-dart-playground/polymer1/blob/master/dom_repeat_model/web/app_element.dart#L35 to check if it works for you as well.

Comment: I included the tag `data-index$="{{index}}"` and works... Günter,  you are very helpful! Thanks a lot!